# href en laravel desde jquery error 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, href

Estoy tratando de hacer en mi jquery un enlace con html a una ruta laravel para ello estoy creando una variable:

```
var url = config.url.base_url + "event/" + eventUrl;
```

config.url.base_url es una variable que está en el archivo de configuración de Laravel, que me devuelve la URL donde estoy le concateno event y la url del evento que viene de la DB.

he creado mi routa en **web.php**

```
/** SHOW EVENT INFO */
Route::post('event/{url}', 'Web\EventController@showEvent');
```

y ahora si en el href, le concateno la variable url:

```
'<a target="_blank" id="button-event-read" href="'+url+'" class="btn color2-bg float-btn">Leer más.<i class="fal fa-angle-right"></i></a>';
```

al ponerme encima del botón la URL aparece perfecta, pero al intentar ir a ella, siempre me devuelve un error 404... En el controlador, simplemente tengo un echo de momento:

```
public function showEvent($url){
        echo "llego";
    }
```

que estoy haciendo mal¿?? Gracias por la ayuda de antemano

Comment: Que te aparece en la URL de la pagina que sale error?

Comment: @JuanRivera http://localhost/guiaPaladar/event/prueba-2 supuestamente es lo que dewbería aparecer. Lo que pretendo es crear una vista para poder visualizar el evento

Comment: Si pones `localhost/event/prueba-2` te imprime "llego"?

Comment: @JuanRivera no. en todos caso sería localhost/guiaPaladar/event/prueba-2 pero sigue el mismo problema

Comment: @JuanRivera ya lo he solucionado... Aunque es extraño. Hace bastantes horas hice un clear de la cache de laravel y sus rutas... y devolvió todo limpio... pero seguia el problema. me ha dado por borrar manualmente el contenido de bootstrap/cache he recargado la web y ya llega

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el href del anchor es una peticion get por defecto. Debes cambiar la route a Route::get en web.php de laravel routes.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. ya lo he modificado y sigue el mismo problema

Comment: prueba con echo $url en showEvent()